# C# .NET EF Migrations Unable to cast object of type 'System.Double' to type 'System.Single'

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-migrations

Had a working .NET Blazor Application with EF Core in it. I have read of other errors that include the *Unable to cast object of type 'System.Double' to type 'System.Single'* But I do not see how this applies to the Migration functionality on data.

It runs fine when there are no migrations inside the migrations folder. When I add a migration it breaks at the line that has `data.Database.Migrate();`

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, AppDbContext data )
    {
        data.Database.Migrate();
    }
```

Any Suggestions?

Comment: because `data.Database.Migrate();` is applying the migration. and your are providing something wrong. you can not cast object of 64 bt to 32 bit

Comment: I recently used docker to add a mysql + .NET app into a docker-compose file. I got the migration to work this morning, but then just tried again and it is not building when running `dotnet ef migrations add newMigration`.  Im new to using docker so this might be a docker related issue I cant seem to understand.

Comment: my question is? do you need to apply migration on appication startup or not?

Comment: As Vikek mentioned above, we were setting something up wrong. The problem is we had a DbContextFactory.cs that was hardcoded to use SqlServer and the new startup.cs was using the UseMySql. We basically had the migration trying to utilize two different sql server types and it was giving us this error.

Comment: you can add as an answer with an explanation so that it help others

Comment: please see comment below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Vikek mentioned above, we were setting something up wrong. The problem is we had a DbContextFactory.cs that was hardcoded to use SqlServer and the new startup.cs was using the UseMySql. We basically had the migration trying to utilize two different sql server types and it was giving us this error.

Here is the old DBContextFactory file:

```
public AppDbContext CreateDbContext(string[] args)
    {
        var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<AppDbContext>();
        optionsBuilder.SqlServer(@"server=mssqlserver;userid=bigboy;pwd=thesecretpasswordformssql;database=devdb;AllowPublicKeyRetrieval=True;");
        return new AppDbContext(optionsBuilder.Options);

    }
```

Replaced it with:

```
public AppDbContext CreateDbContext(string[] args)
    {
        var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<AppDbContext>();
        optionsBuilder.UseMySql(@"server=mysql;userid=root;pwd=thesecretpassword;port=3306;database=devdb;sslmode=none;AllowPublicKeyRetrieval=True;");
        return new AppDbContext(optionsBuilder.Options);

    }
```

The Startup file was looking at the correct mysql string but the DBContextFactory.cs was causing the errors because it cant migrate the mysql and the mssql types together.

Comment: This should be a comment, and close your question since the problem no longer happens.

Comment: see comment above. I dont think its a good idea to delete this post because it will help someone else out.

Comment: @TanveerBadar but others can also face the kind of issue and which has the same workaround.

Comment: Then mark it as accepted answer. The way it is right now is half-way between two good options.